# UI Automation Performance

Tags: winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I see that traversing UI Tree of of any Application, that supports UI Automation and has about 1k elements, takes time in excess of 8 seconds at least, using UI Automation COM library. Tree Walk is done using Control Walker. I understand it involves inter-process communication to make a call like FindAll and then retrieve further properties.

The response time differs from Application to Application, however, the best I see is still more than aforementioned time.

I tried UI Automation Caching (below sample), however, the initial Tree walk still incurs cost of over 7-8 seconds as well Caching the Parent's properties is not a possibility (or at least I could not get it from Cache even using different types of traversals like TreeScope Descendants and Element or a combination). Just a sample code where I try to Create Condition array on all the available Controls and expecting some Properties to be Cached. The Application has about 1500 controls of which about 800 are visible. It takes roughly 9 seconds for Cache to build up.

```
    private static IUIAutomationCacheRequest BuildCacheRequest()
    {
        IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequest = _automation.CreateCacheRequest();
        cacheRequest.AddProperty(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ControlTypePropertyId);
        cacheRequest.AddProperty(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId);
        ....
        return cacheRequest;
    }       
    private static IUIAutomationCondition BuildConditionArray()
    {
        IUIAutomationCondition[] conditionArray = new IUIAutomationCondition[40];
        int controlType = 50000;

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            conditionArray[i] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, controlType);
            controlType += 1;
        }

        return _automation.CreateOrConditionFromArray(conditionArray);
    }
    
    private static IUIAutomationElementArray FindAllDescendantsBuildCache(IUIAutomationElement element, IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequest, IUIAutomationCondition conditionArray)
    {
        IUIAutomationCondition[] condArr = new IUIAutomationCondition[2];
        condArr[1] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_IsOffscreenPropertyId, false);
        condArr[0] = conditionArray;
        cacheRequest.AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.AutomationElementMode_None;
        cacheRequest.TreeFilter = _automation.ControlViewCondition;

        var cachedElements = element.FindAllBuildCache(TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants,
         _automation.CreateAndConditionFromArray(condArr), cacheRequest);
        return cachedElements;
    }
```

Once Cached, response time is much faster, understandably.

Question I have -
Is there any possibility to Traverse UI Tree carrying about 2k elements within a second or two using UI Automation (or even otherwise)?
I also look to identify the traversed Elements through their properties, just like Properties' support from UI Automation

Just as a side note, I have tried to use Win32 API at basic level like using [EnumChildWindows](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows), however, even that doesn't yield Control handles on different Types of Desktop Frameworks like Electron or WPF.

Comment: have also read through https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4454b41d-8440-422f-983d-341da161a3bb/ui-automation-performance?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation beyond some other posts on this topic

Comment: Electron and Wpf are windowless UI framework. That is why Win32 doesn't help.

Comment: thanks @jtxkopt. I could also spot that through Spy++ that Controls are not actually Windows in the two frameworks, still just wanted to check if there is anything that I missed or could be done differently through Win32 API

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [UI Automation and the UI Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-threading#ui-automation-and-the-ui-thread) You could try using [IUIAutomationTreeWalker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtreewalker) or the [IUIAutomationElement::FindAll method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-findall) and using control patterns.

Comment: You should not traverse a full UI tree with UI Automation (unless you know before hand it's a small one), it's really not meant for that and can not only be super slow, but can also hang for some reason related to the automated app and its internal behavior, for example if it displays a modal dialog (ie: it's not a design flaw, there's nothing one can do for that in the general case). UI automation is made to simulate a real-life end-user action. You should not use FindAll on a whole tree, but use intermediate discriminants (find on properties).

Comment: @SimonMourier - Thanks for the suggestion and I am in agreement that UI Automation use case is predominantly to simulate real-life end-user action.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT - thanks for your suggestion and I will check it. I presume, the moment I try to do FindAll even with a Control Patterns, theoretically it will walk the Tree as well as considering that my intent is to find many Elements in the Tree that could be located at any branch and depth, it should not still be much different in terms of performance, and predominantly why the idea of somehow build the cache as early as possible. Something like that if UI Cache could be built as the Tree is being built

Comment: Because of the way UI Automation uses Windows messages, conflicts can occur when a client application attempts to interact with its own UI on the UI thread. These conflicts can lead to very slow performance.